Failed to run gatling tests with karate: Gatling failed.: ForkException
I am trying to set up performance tests using Gatling framework for the existing Karate tests. However, I am getting a bunch of errors with no idea how to resolve them.
Error log
Build Failure error
I've tried to use different versions of gatling plugin and scala-maven-plugin, but getting the same result.
Have anybody come across this issue? I would be also super grateful to any hints where to dig to solve this problem, and finally run Gatling tests.

do review the guidelines on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and see if these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+gatling
